# Why isn't the う (u) in どうして being pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation, hiragana

According to Google Translate the phrase is pronounced *dōshite* (I've also heard it pronounced like that in anime and movies).

I couldn't help noticing that the う (u) isn't being pronounced. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When う follows a character ending in the "o" sound it extends that sound. The "u" *is* pronounced, but as "o" instead. I recommend listening to examples.

The same thing also happens with い and characters that end with an "e" sound. (Eg. せんせい). The い serves to extend the "e" sound.

It is also extremely crucial to include that extension in both writing and speaking because having it or not having it will change the meaning completely. For example:

> こうこう(koukou)

Means `high school` while

> ここ(koko)

Means `here`

Comment: It should be noted that: 1) えい is occasionally pronounced ei rather than ē, especially in careful speech, and that 2) おう is pronounced as ou if the u is a verb ending (e.g. in 問う「とう」)

Comment: Just to add: The o in dōshite has a bar to note the extended sound. (It can sometimes be written as just doshite but it does get confusing so it is often romanized either as dōshite or doushite)